# WebSVN listing all repositories. But Not showing files

Tags: apache, websvn

Apache version   : Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) 
Operating System : Fedora release 13 (Goddard)

While loading WebSVN, it shows all repositories configured in below file ,But It shows 'Rev 0' while Click on repository name,Please see the attached screen shot.

```
 /var/www/html/websvn/include/config.php

<?php
$config->parentPath("/repos");
$config->addRepository('landfill', 'file:///repos/proj/landfill','Projects');
$config->setTemplatePath("$locwebsvnreal/templates/calm/");
$config->setMinDownloadLevel(2);
set_time_limit(0);
$config->expandTabsBy(8);
?>
```

[image: But It shows 'Rev 0' while Click on repository name]

Comment: Do you have any sample config files for your setup to share? I'm running WebSVN with my own svnserve running and it is working fine. Specifically I'd be interested in seeing your config.php and also are you running svnserve on the same box?

Comment: Hi @slm I added content of config.php file above , Yes as you asked both are running in same system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Menu sytem>Administration>SElinuxManagement Disabled Selinux and now it working Fine!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try.

#### First here's my `config.php`:

```
$config->parentPath('/proj/lamolabs.org/scm/svn');
$config->addTemplatePath($locwebsvnreal.'/templates/calm/');
$config->useTreeIndex(true); // Tree index, open by default
$config->setShowLastModInListing(true);
$config->addInlineMimeType('text/plain');
$config->allowDownload();
$config->setMinDownloadLevel(2);
$config->useGeshi();
set_time_limit(0);
$config->expandTabsBy(2);
```

#### Second, I setup my own start/stop script, `/etc/init.d/svnserve`, for svnserve:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Control script for the Subversion daemon
#
# chkconfig: 2345 89 40
# description: Subversion daemon
#
# processname: svnserve

source /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

[ -x /usr/bin/svnserve ] || exit 1

### Default variables
SYSCONFIG="/etc/sysconfig/subversion"

### Read configuration
[ -r "$SYSCONFIG" ] && source "$SYSCONFIG"

RETVAL=0
prog="svnserve"
desc="Subversion daemon"

start() {
  echo -n $"Starting $desc ($prog): "
  daemon $prog -d $OPTIONS
  RETVAL=$?
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
  echo
}

stop() {
  echo -n $"Shutting down $desc ($prog): "
  killproc $prog
  RETVAL=$?
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success || failure
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog
  return $RETVAL
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  condrestart)
    [ -e /var/lock/subsys/$prog ] && restart
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart}"
    RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

#### Third, I setup a config file, `/etc/sysconfig/subversion`, for `svnserve`

```
# Configuration file for the Subversion service
#
# To pass additional options (for instace, -r root of directory to server) to
# the svnserve binary at startup, set OPTIONS here.
#
#OPTIONS=
OPTIONS="--threads --root /proj/lamolabs.org"
```

I wrote about how I set this up on my [blog](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/) in a post titled: [Git and subversion setup on CentOS 5](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/401/git-and-subversion-setup-on-centos-5/). The post has some additional info that might be helpful.

Let me know how you make out, I'm curious to find out what's up with your setup.

**EDIT #2**

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ServerName websvn.lamolabs.org
  ServerAlias websvn.bubba.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/websvn/current
  <Directory /var/www/websvn/current>
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi @slm those two links to blog is not working[ may be temporary issue , will check after sometime]

I have one more question, that while setting up WenSvn did you done any modification in apache configurations ?

Comment: Hi @slm,

I observed one more thing , this may helps to pin point the issue.

in file /var/www/websvn/include/config.php , I removed all $config->addRepository entries, and retained  only 
$config->parentPath('/repos/proj');

But in this condition while loading  '//myserver/websvn/' page 
It shows below error!

Please set up a repository path in include/config.php using $config->parentPath or $config->addRepository

See the installation guide for more details

Comment: Hi @slm  
I installed **Apache** and **Websvn** in an another **Ubuntu** system which worked without any configuration changes ..

Comment: Yes that's been my experience with it as well, it generally just works. You might want to compare the versions of Apache, PHP, SVN, etc. and see if there isn't something up with the particular versions you're using.

Comment: Hi @slm Which is your operating system?

Comment: CentOS 5.x. I've also run it on Fedora 14 as well.